# Ghostscript command for finding the number of colors used for each page in pdf file

Tags: ghostscript

I'm new to GhostScript. Can you let me know the Ghostscript command for finding the number of colors used for each page in pdf file. I need to parse the results of this command from java program

Answer (score 0):

There is no such Ghostscript command or device. It would also be difficult to figure out; so much depends on what you mean. Do you intend to count the colour of each pixel in every image for example ? Which colour spaces are you interested in ? What about ICCBased colour spaces, do you want the component values, or the CIE values ?

[edit]

Yeah there's no Ghostscript equivalent, I did say that.

You wuold have to intercept every call to the colour operators, examine the components being supplied and see if they were no black and white. For example, if you set a CMYK colour with C=M=Y=0 and K!=0 then its still black and white. Similar arguments apply for RGB, CIE and ICC colour spaces.

Now I bet ImageMagick doesn't do that, I suspect it simply uses Ghostscript to render a bitmap (probably RGB) and then counts the number of pixels of each colour in the output. Image manipulation tools pretty much all have to have a way to do that counting already, so its a low cost for them.

Its also wrong.

It doesn't tell you anything about the original colour. If you render a colour object to a colour space that is different to the one it was specified in, then the rendering engine has to convert it from the colour space it was in, to the expected one. This often leads to colour shifts, especially when converting from RGB to CMYK but any conversion will potentially have this problem.

So if this is what ImageMagick is doing, its inaccurate at best. It is possible to write PostScript to do this accurately, with some effort, but exactly what counts as 'colour' and 'black and white' is still a problem. You haven't said why you want to know if an input file is 'black and white' (you also haven't said if gray counts as black and white, its not the same thing)

I'm guessing you intend to either charge more for colour printing, or need to divert colour input to a different printer. In which case you do need to know if the PDF uses (eg) R=G=B=1 for black, because that often will *not* result in C=M=Y=0 K=1 when rendered to the printer. Not only that, but the exact colour produced may not even be the same from one printer to another (colour conversion is device-dependent), so just because Ghostscript produced pure black doesn't mean that another printer would.

This is not a simple subject.

Comment: Ken! I'm looking for Ghostscript's equivalent command for this ImageMagick command identify -format "%k "  filename. This command outputs the no of colors used for each page in pdf. If the number of colors is 2, we assume it's black and white otherwise it's not black and white.

Comment: Edited answer, too long for comments